# Can't add notice after xhr request. Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xmlhttprequest

File is added and right redirected, but without notice. If you don't use xhr, notice shows.

**application.js**

```
var files = evt.target.files || evt.dataTransfer.files;

// files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("POST", 'report_drag', false);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
   xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", "file." + f.name.split('.').pop());
   xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
   xhr.send(f);
}
```

**controller.rb**

```
def report_drag
    filename = "report/#{DateTime.now.year}-#{DateTime.now.month}/" + "#{Vendor.where(id: current_user.id).first.title}" + "#{File.extname("#{request.headers['HTTP_X_FILENAME']}")}"
    File.open(File.join(filename), "wb") { |f| f.write(request.body.read) }
    redirect_to report_url, notice: "Файл успешно добавлен."
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a simple request from the browser(using a `link` or a `button`, or simply writing in the address bar), the response replaces the current page and is rendered instead of it.

When you use `XHR`, the browser does not change it current location and does not render anything - it assumes that the caller (the javascript code) is responsible for reading the response, and making sense out of it.

If you want to asynchronously communicate with the server, and use its responses to re-render (parts) of the page, read this [tutorial for using rails with `Ajax`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)